# iPhone Recent Calls Details View - Custom Cell?

Tags: iphone

I would like to have something that would kind of replicate the details view of the recent calls tab on the iPhone phone.app.

When viewing the recent calls, tapping the disclosure button takes me to the view pictured here: http://img337.imageshack.us/img337/3456/recentcalls.jpg

I would like to know if that area in blue represents a custom cell. Am I right? Or is there an easier way to accomplish this?

My need for replicating this comes from my trouble with `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, as explained here: [heightForRowAtIndexPath for only one section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189287/heightforrowatindexpath-for-only-one-section)

(I won't be using heightForRowAtIndexPath anymore with this solution).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the area you've outlined in blue is the section header for the first section. You could also just use the table header.

Matt Gallagher posted a [nice article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) on customizing your table header.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, it is likely a custom section header view, glued together from various labels and other widgets.

It would certainly seem much, much easier IMO to do this with a custom table view header view than with a custom table view cell.

See the table view delegate method [`-tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:) where you return your custom `UIView` object for a given section.

Comment: It is indeed much easier to customize the tableview header. Thanks for the answer.